# Where can I add a trigger on the ChatterMessage object?

Tags: chatter

I want to use the fields of the ChatterMessage object. So I made an instance of ChatterMessage but then where do I have to make a trigger for ChatterMessage?

```
//list
public List<ChatterMessage> filterChatterMessage(List<ChatterMessage> cm)
{
    system.debug('filterChatterMessage:'+cm);
    return filterBody(fm);
}

public List<SObject> filterBody(List<SObject> sobjs)
{
    for (SOBject feedObject: sobjs)
    {
        if(feedObject instanceOf ChatterMessage)
        { 
            body = ((ChatterMessage)feedObject).Body;
            ConversationId = ((ChatterMessage)feedObject).ConversationId;
            SenderId = ((ChatterMessage)feedObject).SenderId;                
            SentDate = ((ChatterMessage)feedObject).SentDate;
        }
        else
        {
            ........
        }
    }
}
```

So where do I have to make a trigger for the ChatterMessage?

Answer (score 5):

Chatter messenger doesn't have an API as yet - I believe it is on the roadmap.

Comment: The roadmap for Chatter Messenger is pretty grim now. Not available in orgs created after Spring '16, and unsupported after Spring '17. https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_chatter_messenger_eol.htm